# Sum fields in a column if there is an entry in a corresponding row in another column

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula, lookup

Assume the following data:

```
  | A        B        C
--+------------------------
1 | 2        3        5
2 | 2                 3
3 | 4                 4
4 |          2        3
5 |          5        6
```

In cell `A6`, I want Excel to add cells `C1`, `C2`, `C3` on the basis that `A1`, `A2` and `A3` have data in. Similarly, I want `B6` to add together `C1`, `C4` and `C5` because `B1`, `B4` and `B5` have data.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `SUMIF` formula will work

```
=SUMIF(A$1:A$5,"<>",$C$1:$C$5)
```

Place that formula is cell `A6` and then copy it to `B6`.

Answer (score 2):

In **A6** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C1:$C5)*(A1:A5<>""))
```

and then copy to **B6**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create another column, e.g. `AValue`, with the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,A1)` in it. This will return `0` if the cell in `A` in the corresponding line is empty, or the value from the cell in `A` otherwise.

Then you can just sum up the values of the new column.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In truth, however, I have 30 columns that need this doing to, not just the 2 and large parts of my spreadsheet are locked for editing, so it needs to be a 1 cell solution.